# pgm resolution problem

Tags: navigation, mapping, resolution, pgm, sbpl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SBPL Lattice planner has a map resolution 0.025, and I have a map with a resolution of 0.05. How can I change my map .pgm file in a resolution of 0.025?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/165846/pgm-resolution-problem/) by [Ico](https://answers.ros.org/users/17981/ico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can open your pgm in an image editing program such as gimp or photoshop, double the resolution, and save it.

You should also be able to resize it using imagemagik tools such as `mogrify` or `convert`.

If you have a yaml file that goes with your pgm map, you should edit the resolution there; otherwise, just pass the new resolution to the map_server on startup.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2015-03-07**:
@Ico and @ahendrix ,i think the map resolution  0.05 represents 0.05m/cell,how to use gimp to change the map resolution is 0.025? in my case,my map.pgm is (576,512),does   change the map.pgm size (1152,1024) can change the resolution??

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-03-07**:
The resolution in your map yaml file specifies how the map is interpreted (how big a cell is). The image size (in pixels) multiplied by the resolution determines the final map size (in meters).

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2015-03-08**:
@adhendrix,thank  you ,does  you  mean that  if  i  want to double the map resolution  , i can just individually reduce the length and width of the image  by half ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-03-08**:
No. Please ask a new question and give a specific example of what you're trying to do. Include the map.yaml and the pgm file you're trying to resize.

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2015-03-08**:
Thanks , i'm  sorry ,it is my  [question  link](http://answers.ros.org/question/204499/how-to-double-the-resolution-of-the-map/)